# Fill down by number specified in userform with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created this UserForm
[image: Picture of the UserForm]

I am trying to AutoFill the generated hostname in series by the number of hostnames specified in the UserForm. For Example, if I need 12 hostnames, I enter 12 into the userform and it copies the generated hostname 12 times. (...-FAH34-01,FAH34-02,FAH34-03 etc.)

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim H As String
Dim X As Long

H = -FAH32 - 1
X = TextBox3.Value

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1.Value

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = TextBox2.Value
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "-FAH34-01"

Range("R3").Value = X

End Sub
```

TextBox 1 is the Sales Order.
TextBox 2 is the Hostname.
TextBox 3 is the Number of hostnames desired.

Currently it prints the Sales Order in the active cell and then the hostname into the cell below that. I would like it to then take that hostname and copy it down in series. Much like it would work if you grabbed the handle at the bottom right of the cell and dragged it down. However, I want to know if it's possible to only copy down by the amount specified in the UserForm.

---

I did get this to work.

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim H As String
Dim X As Long, i As Long

H = "-FAH34"
X = Me.TextBox3.Value

ActiveCell.Value = "SO #" & TextBox1
    
For i = 1 To X
    Application.ActiveCell(i + 2) = TextBox2.Value & "-FAH34-" & Format(i, "00")
Next i
    
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below sub-

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim H As String
Dim X As Long, i As Long

H = "-FAH34"
X = Me.TextBox3.Value

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = Me.TextBox2.Value
    
    For i = 1 To X
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i + 2) = "-FAH34-" & Format(i, "00")
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That is very close but I need the site number from TextBox2 to be in front of the "-FAH34-00"

Comment: Ope, I think I got it how I want now. Thank you so much you're a genius!

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to make this repeatable for multiple Sales Orders down the same column?

Comment: Yes, I think possible. You need another for loop then. Glad to know it helps.